# Can't compile C++ in linux mint with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, linux-mint

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int intake;

    cout<<"Enter the maximum number of intake in this session of 2015, September: ";
    cin>>intake;

    for(int i=20150900; i<intake+20150900; i++){
        cout<<"Enter the total percentage of Student ID numbered #"<<i<<": ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my code and when i compile it on code::blocks it gives the following error. I am new to linux OS so i dont know much about how it all works. Thankx for your help! :)
Error Message:

> g++   -c /home/subbs/Desktop/entrance_exam/main.cpp -o
>   /home/subbs/Desktop/entrance_exam/main.o /bin/sh: 1: g++: not found

Comment: Maybe need to install `GCC`. Maybe look for it in your package manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the terminal and enter `sudo apt-get install g++`.  This will take care of install g++ and everything else you will need.  It is real easy.

Answer (score 7):

You need to install the compiler. Run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

And then, try again to compile.

**UPDATE:**

If when you're trying to run the program, you get an error message like this:

```
Process terminated with status 255
```

It's because code blocks tries to run the program with `xterm` by default, and it may be the case that you don' have it installed. To solve it you have to go to:

`Settings > Environment`

And in the drop down menu next to **Terminal to launch console programs** choose your terminal. In the case of Linux Mint, it was `gnome-terminal --disable-factory -t $TITLE -x`

[- source](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1597)

Comment: Yeah thankx. It did compile but im still not able to run the code.

Comment: is there something more i should do?

Comment: like.. i hit the build and run button and it builds but doesnt run.

Comment: I'm not very used to code blocks, does it says any error message or something like that ?

Comment: > g++   -c /home/subbs/Desktop/entrance_exam/main.cpp -o /home/subbs/Desktop/entrance_exam/main.o
g++  -o /home/subbs/Desktop/entrance_exam/main /home/subbs/Desktop/entrance_exam/main.o   
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
 
Checking for existence: /home/subbs/Desktop/entrance_exam/main
Executing: xterm -T '/home/subbs/Desktop/entrance_exam/main' -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner "/home/subbs/Desktop/entrance_exam/main" (in /home/subbs/Desktop/entrance_exam)
Process terminated with status 255 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: this is all it says. wtf

Comment: Okay, that 255 error code (i had the same in Linux Mint too) it's because after compiling, code blocks tries to run the program with a console, and by default it uses `xterm` what it's not installed by default in Mint. To change the console, you have to go to `Settings > Environment` and in the drop down that says `Terminal to launch console programs` choose  `gnome-terminal --disable-factory -t $TITLE -x`. [Source](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1597)

Comment: Sorry I have already edited the message, I accidentally pressed enter hahahah.

Comment: i dont see 'Environment' in the settings dude! or anything similar, to that matter. What do i do?

Comment: Which version of code blocks do you have ? [Environmnet menu](http://i60.tinypic.com/jabfcw.png)